# El objeto Date no está funcionando bien

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

tengo un gran problema con un objeto tipo **Date** ya que si únicamente imprimo ese objeto la hora y la fecha es *correcta*, pero si obtengo individualmente cada uno la fecha es *incorrecta*. Acá les pongo un ejemplo:

***Código***

```
const date = new Date()

console.log(date)
console.log('Hoy es día ' + date.getDay())
```

En el código no parece haber nada malo pero el **resultado es este**:

[image: Resultado del código anterior]

Acá pueden ver que el día en la primera linea (pasar date a String) es 05, que está bien, pero al usar el método getDay() me lanza otro día.

No puedo sólo restarle 1 porque pasa despues de la 5 de la tarde, antes de esa hora los días si están bien.

Por si les sirve estoy utilizando ***Google Chrome***.

Comment: Antes de utilizar algo te recomiendo que veas para que sirve. getDay te devuelve valores de 0-6 y considerando 0 a domingo, está devolviendo el resultado esperado.

Comment: El método `getDay` devuelve el día de la semana identificándolo en por el índice que ocupan, (*entonces en este caso es correcto por lo que ya te expone el otro compañero*), sugiero leas [aqui a detalle](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay)

Comment: Debes usar [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDate) para que te devuelva el número del día en el mes.

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar el método `TolocaleString` que proporciona `Date`.
En tu ejemplo sería así:

```js
    const date = new Date()
    
    console.log(date)
    console.log('Hoy es día ' + date.toLocaleDateString("es-mx", {weekday: "long"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

> El valor devuelto por getDay() es un entero correspondiente al día de
> la semana; siendo 0 (Domingo) el primer día, 1 (Lunes) el segundo,
> etcétera.

Para obtener el resultado que estas buscando deberas crear un arreglo con los dias de la semana iniciando por el domingo.

```
const dias = ['Domingo', 'Lune', 'Marte', 'Miercole', 'Jueve', 'Vierne', 'Sabado'];
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

const date = new Date();

console.log(dias[date.getDay()]);
//Sabado

console.log(days[date.getDay()]);
//Saturday
```

Esto nos permite determinar el dia para cualquier idioma. [Mas informacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDay).